# Is it possible to expand variable in bash (posix) stored as another varable?

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, variable-assignment

For education purpose I'm trying to write a small script to test difference between quoted and unquoted Special parameters in bash. Particularly, $*,"$*",$@ and "$@"

Roughly speaking, I'm trying to get both name and value of Special parameter inside the for loop when the name of Special parameters are stored inside the array

`script`

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=','
args='$*,"$*"'
for a in ${args} 
do
  echo "$a"         # Outputs $* or "$*"
  echo $(echo "$a") # Outputs the same
                    # but desired output is the value of variable stored inside $a
  echo "${!a}"      # Doesn't work. Indirect expansion?
done
```

If I put the value of the `args` variable in single quotes (`args='$*,"$*"'`), I get the names of parameters inside the for loop.
If I put the value of the `args` variable in double quotes (`args="$*,\"$*\""`), I get the values of special parameters inside the loop.
But I need both. And names and 'values of values'.

I've tried indirect expansion, but I'm not sure if I use it correctly or not

e.g. when I run script with several arguments: `./script arg1 arg2`
I expect this output:

```
$*          <-------value of $args
arg1        <-------values of 'value of $args', i.e echo $*
arg2
"$*"        <-------the second iteration
arg1 arg2   <--values of 'value of $args', i.e. echo "$*"
```

Bash solution is acceptable, but if it is a Posix solution it would be excellent

UPDATE:
To sum up, this goal can be achieved (separate cases with double quotes/without them or use eval(somehow dangerous)) but as BashFAQ says it is highly not recommended to store something in variables other than strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an indirect expansion, the value of `a` should only be the name of the indirect variable. For example:

```
f() {
  name='*' # name only, no $
  echo "${!name}"
}
f 1 2 3 # prints '1 2 3'
IFS=: 1 2 3 # prints '1:2:3'
```

Trying to put the quoted and unquoted forms into a variable and expand like that requires more than indirection. As written you'd probably need `eval`. See: [Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quoting-characters-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-varia)

That seems excessive though. Wouldn't it be simpler to take the name and expand it twice with and without quotes?

```
test_expansion() {
  name=$1 ; shift
  printf '%s with quotes:\n' "${name}"
  printf ' <%s>\n' "${!name}"
  printf '%s without quotes:\n' "${name}"
  printf ' <%s>\n' ${!name}
}
test_expansion "*" 1 2 3
test_expansion "@" 1 2 3
```

Comment: Again those a special parameters. So $* and "$*" differ. So may be indirection is not my case. Because for ordinary variables I managed to perform it. I understand that sh is quite ancient scripting language and there could be some task it can't perform at all. By the way, in your link there is another link to [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). And if I understand it right the author doesn't recommend to store commands and variables in variables.

Comment: @sch1024 : *"..the author doesn't recommend to store commands and variables in variables"*. YES, this is correct. You may be able to make your particular case work, but it will be brittle and fail when there is "oh one more thing". If you hope to move up in your organization, you will be the only person how understands how your code works, so you'll be stuck fixing those "oh one more thing"s. (-; AND generally, such things are a maintenance night mare, you may not remember 6 months later why something works, let alone your replacement (-; ! Good luck.

Comment: ok, I can  accept No as an answer :)

Comment: @sch1024, note that `$@` and `"$@"` also differ (a lot). You just need to test with values containing whitespace, e.g. `test_expansion "@" oneword "two words"`

Comment: @ilkkachu, yeap, you are absolutely right. They all differ and not only about whitespaces but also in the amount of tokens (fields) they produce and whether IFS contain whitespace and what is its first character... and so on.   
Quite convenient :(

Comment: @sch1024, well. The way I see it, it's easiest to think that `"$@"` and `"$*"` have two different meanings (one gives the whole list, one joins it to a single string). And to forget about the variants without quotes since they're not at all very useful.

Answer (score 0):

To use indirection (reference), check:

```
$ foo=bar
$ declare -n qux=foo
$ echo $qux
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you're doing `a='$*'`. The `$` isn't part of the variable name. This should work:

```bash
a="*"
echo "${!a}"
```

Comment: Can you make an example with double qoutes?

$* is *

"$*" is ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `$*` and `"$*"` are the same variable, and the only way to print it is like I showed above (or with `declare -n a='*'`). This feature is for making variables which expand to another variable, not variables which expand to any arbitrary expression. If you want that, use `eval`.

Comment: According to Bash manual: $* expands to several strings with one argument in it; "$*" expands to one string with all arguments in it. And the same for $@ and "$@". Those are Special parameters. So the whole purpose of that script is to check this behavior. I can write 4 different loops for each case and I've done so and it works. But as I'm learning I decide to put this 4 for loops inside another loop. Cause next time there can be 12 loops or 120 loops.

Comment: For `$*`, the behavior around quotes is the same as any other bash variable. For `$@`, there is a special behavior, and so what you need to test is `${!a}` vs `"${!a}"`. You cannot store the quotes inside of `a`. There is only one variable named `@`, it just behaves differently based on the wider expression it's in.

Comment: @Verpous The behavior of `$*` is somewhat different when quoted, you get a single word like a normal variable but that word is created by joining the elements of the array with the first character of `IFS`.